# Removing an application from recent applications stack android

Tags: android

I m launching in built map application from my application now on pressing back button from the map app.. I need to clear the map app from the recent stack as it is then independent from my app and of no use..

Comment: @DavidJhons - that is not applicable, as it concerns things that can be done to the configuration of the target activity.  In this case, the target activity does not belong to the poster, so they cannot modify its configuration.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Thanks for pointing out, really appeciate and i have removed the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question properly then this is your answer.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
                            SecondActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;

You may need to get the package name using "getPackageManager()" of Map application, and then get the process id of it and then stop the map application when you quitting from your app.